# CSS div auto size to contents, with max width and elipsis text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stlye something like this, so the container's width auto sizes given the longest text on each row.

[image]

But I want a max-width on the container, and if thats exceeded then I want an elipsis to show on the truncated text.

[image]

Each row has its own indent, and I want the mouse over to operate on the whole row.

I've had a crack at this, but it's just not working for me...

https://jsfiddle.net/sprotty/wfdkeq1L/18/

```css
.component-body-inputs {
  max-width: 500px;
  width:fit-content(); /* doesn't seem to do anything*/
  background-color: yellow;  
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.component-body-inputs>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
}

.component-body-inputs>div>img {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.component-body-inputs>div>div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* doesn't seem to do anything*/

}

.component-body-inputs>div:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
  <div class="component-body-inputs">
    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:0em" src="Icon.png" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:1em" src="Ico.pngn" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:2em" src="icon.png" />
      <div>Item1hshksdh fh sdfjhsjkdfhs fsd</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:2em" src="icon.png" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

(Note the html and css can be completely changed, I just need an element which represents the row to hang events on).

CSS is not really my thing, so please explain things with that in mind!

Comment: overlow:hidden is required to trigger ellipsis

Comment: @G-Cyr Even with that enabled, this code still does not trigger an ellipsis

Comment: also a width is required to set when overflow happens .. inline-block is not a good idea (it will itself overflow from its parent) , but a flex structure is as advised by @temaniafif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fit-content()` need to be used with value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content). Without it's invalid.

By the way you don't need it and you can update your code like below. I will rely on flexbox to make it easier since you want to have all the elements in the same row next to each other.

```css
.component-body-inputs {
  max-width: 200px;
  display:inline-block; /* to fit the content width OR display:table to keep the block level behavior */
  background-color: yellow;  
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.component-body-inputs>div {
  /*overflow: hidden; not needed here*/
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  display:flex; /* added this */
}

.component-body-inputs>div>img {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.component-body-inputs>div>div {
  /*display: inline-block; not needed*/
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; /*needed here*/

}

.component-body-inputs>div:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-body-inputs">
    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:0em" src="Icon.png" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:1em" src="Ico.pngn" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:2em" src="icon.png" />
      <div>Item1hshksdh fh sdfjhsjkdfhs fsd</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:2em" src="icon.png" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Many thanks that seems to work perfectly, and answered so quickly, I've been messing wi this for hours...Ill have a read about flexbox, it looks like it could solve a few other issues i'm having.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.component-body-inputs>div>div` otherwise it won't work. You should also get rid of `display: inline-flex` and instead put `display: flex;` on the parent (`.component-body-inputs>div`) which will make the children appear inline with respect to each other.

```css
.component-body-inputs {
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;  
}


.component-body-inputs>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
   white-space: nowrap;
  display:flex;
}

.component-body-inputs>div>img {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.component-body-inputs>div>div {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* doesn't seem to do anything*/
}

.component-body-inputs>div:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
  <div class="component-body-inputs">
    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:0em" src="Icon.png" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:1em" src="Ico.pngn" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:2em" src="icon.png" />
      <div>Item1hshkbnjmbn,sd   hjmflkj;jlk;jkl;klhg</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="padding-left:2em" src="icon.png" />
      <div>Item1</div>
    </div>

  </div>
```